# Matching the variable names to the values of a variable in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with the following variables:

```
date=c("30/03/2018","30/03/2018","30/03/2018","30/03/2018","30/03/2018","30/03/2018","30/03/2018","30/03/2018")
hour=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
location=c(North,South,East,West,North,South,East,West)
North=c(10,30,40,50,0,40,31,11)
South=c(20,10,20,0,0,0,5,0)
East=c(0,10,10,5,0,0,5,0)
West=c(5,30,40,50,0,40,31,11)
df <- data.frame(date, hour, location, North, South, East, West)
```

`location` represents the place where the observation is seen. The columns, `North`, `South`, `East` and `West` show the average rainfall in those regions. First, I would need to create a column, `Actual` to depict the rainfall in the `location`. For instance, for row 1, the value for `Actual` would be 10 since it is in the North. Next, I would need to create two other columns, `High1` and `High2`. The former represents the highest rainfall in the remaining 3 regions in that hour and the latter represents the second highest rainfall in the remaining 3 regions. For instance, for row 1, the values for `High1` and `High2` are 20 and 5 respectively since in that hour the South and West have the highest and second highest recorded values.

Is there a recommended command(s) that I could use for this setup? Thank you.

Comment: How do you know for 1st row `Actual` value is in `North`? Can you show first few lines of expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Try this (I am sure there are many simpler solutions):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  left_join(
    df %>%
      mutate(n = row_number()) %>%
      pivot_longer(North:West, names_to = "loc", values_to = "rainfall") %>%
      group_by(n) %>%
      mutate(actual = max(ifelse(location==loc,rainfall,0))) %>%
      filter(location != loc) %>%
      arrange(-rainfall) %>%
      mutate(high = paste0("High", row_number())) %>%
      filter(row_number() < 3) %>%
      select(-loc, -n) %>%
      pivot_wider(names_from = high, values_from = rainfall)  %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      arrange(n) %>% select(-n) )

#         date hour location North South East West actual High1 High2
# 1 30/03/2018    1    North    10    20    0    5     10    20     5
# 2 30/03/2018    1    South    30    10   10   30     10    30    30
# 3 30/03/2018    1     East    40    20   10   40     10    40    40
# 4 30/03/2018    1     West    50     0    5   50     50    50     5
# 5 30/03/2018    2    North     0     0    0    0      0     0     0
# 6 30/03/2018    2    South    40     0    0   40      0    40    40
# 7 30/03/2018    2     East    31     5    5   31      5    31    31
# 8 30/03/2018    2     West    11     0    0   11     11    11     0
```

**Data**

```
date <- c("30/03/2018","30/03/2018","30/03/2018","30/03/2018","30/03/2018","30/03/2018","30/03/2018","30/03/2018")
hour <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
location <- c("North","South","East","West","North","South","East","West")
North <- c(10,30,40,50,0,40,31,11)
South <- c(20,10,20,0,0,0,5,0)
East <- c(0,10,10,5,0,0,5,0)
West <- c(5,30,40,50,0,40,31,11)
df <- data.frame(date, hour, location, North, South, East, West)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code, which uses the `nth` function from the **Rfast** package to obtain the second highest rainfall in the remaining regions.

```
library(Rfast)

NSEW <- grep("North|South|East|West", names(df))
i.col <- sapply(df$location, function(x) grep(x, names(df)))
df$Actual <- as.numeric(df[cbind(1:nrow(df), i.col)])   
df[cbind(1:nrow(df), i.col)] <- 0         
df$High1 <- apply(df[,NSEW], 1, max) # *       
df$High2 <- apply(df[,NSEW], 1, Rfast::nth, k=2, descending=TRUE) # *
df[cbind(1:nrow(df), i.col)] <- df$Actual   
df
```

---

```
        date hour location North South East West Actual High1 High2
1 30/03/2018    1    North    10    20    0    5     10    20     5
2 30/03/2018    1    South    30    10   10   30     10    30    30
3 30/03/2018    1     East    40    20   10   40     10    40    40
4 30/03/2018    1     West    50     0    5   50     50    50     5
5 30/03/2018    2    North     0     0    0    0      0     0     0
6 30/03/2018    2    South    40     0    0   40      0    40    40
7 30/03/2018    2     East    31     5    5   31      5    31    31
8 30/03/2018    2     West    11     0    0   11     11    11     0
```

---

* Can also use `rownth`, which returns the nth smallest value for each row:

```
df$High1 <- Rfast::rownth(as.matrix(df[,NSEW]), elems=rep(1, nrow(df)), descending=TRUE)
df$High2 <- Rfast::rownth(as.matrix(df[,NSEW]), elems=rep(2, nrow(df)), descending=TRUE)
```

Comment: Could you use rownth instead?

Comment: Yes, you should know. ;)

Comment: I know, I am the maintainer. Now I am working on a function that returns the "n" smallest or highest values. This should fit here perfectly decreasing the run time.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to use tidyverse, here is an alternative:

```
date <- c("30/03/2018","30/03/2018","30/03/2018","30/03/2018","30/03/2018","30/03/2018","30/03/2018","30/03/2018")
hour <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
loc <- c("North","South","East","West","North","South","East","West")
North <- c(10,30,40,50,0,40,31,11)
South <- c(20,10,20,0,0,0,5,0)
East <- c(0,10,10,5,0,0,5,0)
West <- c(5,30,40,50,0,40,31,11)
location <- list(North, South, East, West, North, South, East, West)



actual <- numeric(length(location))
High1 <- numeric(length(location))
High2 <- numeric(length(location))
for (i in 1:length(location)){
  actual[i] <- (location[[i]][i])
  location[[i]][i] <- 0
  High1[i] <- max(sapply(location , `[` , i))
}
short_location <- location[c(1:4)]
for (i in 1:length(location)){
  n <- length(short_location)
  High2[i] <- sort(sapply(short_location , `[` , i), partial=n-1)[n-1]
}
df <- data.frame(date, hour, loc, North, South, East, West, actual, High1, High2)
```